# React Native Native-Stack: disable transition animation on iOS

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

React Native 0.68 with Native-Stack: transition animation is disabled on android but not on iOS 15.4.1(screen slides from right to left).

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform} from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import Map from './screens/map';
import Splash from './screens/splash';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return ( 
      <NavigationContainer>  
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Splash">
          <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={Splash} options={{headerShown: false, gestureEnabled: false, animation: 'none'}}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="Map" component={Map} options={{headerShown: false, gestureEnabled: false, animation: 'none'}}/>
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer> 
    );
  }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Try this prop https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/#animation you need to pass none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For native stack, you can use the presets provided by the library or disable by passing 'none' to the animation props.

It is an option so it can be passed to the navigator as a screenOptions or can be configured per screen with options.

Added a working demo - https://snack.expo.dev/Hq4U52f0i

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/#animation

Comment: I did, but works only on android.

Comment: In that case, it is a bug, will check the issue.

Comment: Just created a snack demo and I can confirm it is working. https://snack.expo.dev/Hq4U52f0i

Comment: Click that tick icon to mark as solved, if the answer solved your issue @FlorinR